# Why does my "echo" only display 1 word? (Linux-Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a username.txt which shows the username and group, separated by a ",". I'm trying to copy only the usernames from the "visitor" group to a new txt.

my usernamet.txt:

```
mark,staff
jason,visitor
jack,visitor
orlando,visitor
```

This is my current bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=username.txt

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
 if [ $group1 = "visitor" ]; then
   echo $username1 > reportvisitors.txt
 fi
done < $username
```

my reportvisitors.txt

expected output:

```
jason
jack
orlando
```

actual output:

```
jack
```

Comment: Please change `echo $username1 > reportvisitors.txt` to `echo $username1 >> reportvisitors.txt` and it should fly then(is what I could see the issue without running your code as of now). Why because you need to keep appending output into the file which is `>>` operator. Kindly try it out and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 but the thing is i dont want it append continuously, i want it to overwrite everytime when i update my username.txt with new users.

Comment: See answers to your last question.

Comment: Actually, my output shows orlando which makes sense, since it is the last entry in your input file.

Comment: Any reason to not use awk: `awk -F, '$2=="visitor"{print $1 > "reportvisitors.txt"}' "$username"`?

Comment: If you want to overwrite once per run, put the `> reportvisitors.txt` after the `done`. That way you still truncate the file, but you're truncating it once per loop, not once per `echo`.

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of bugs in here (and, as of this writing, in all the proposed answers) related to bad quoting -- try testing what happens when a visitor has a username of `*`. Running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ is always a good idea.

Comment: @JamesBrown i actually did thought of using that, but i wanted to see if i can do it with $username1 instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy isit something like this ? https://ibb.co/PYcC4sN

Comment: @Kinja, if you're going to use a pastebin, please use something that lets you paste code _as text_ and doesn't have ads; https://gist.github.com/ is a great choice, as is http://ix.io/. That said, the way that code differs from what I suggested is that it still has a `> outfile` on the `echo`. Remove that, and _only_ have one on the `done`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy dk what went wrong https://ibb.co/dKSk5Hk . :/

Comment: I'm not following another link to `ibb.co`, for the reasons already given. Its ads bypass my ad blocker and are damned annoying; and the image gets blown up into something blocky and hard to read on my high-resolution screen. If you want me to follow a link to see your code, please use one of the two ad-free, text-centric pastebins linked above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh shit, i went to delete <  $username which caused the bash error. stupid me. Thanks Charles!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's basically done < $username > reportvisitors.txt right?

Comment: That's right. As edited, Richard Jessop's answer is the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the io redirection operator to the end of the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

username=username.txt

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
 if [ "$group1" = "visitor" ]; then
   echo "$username1"
 fi
done < "$username" > reportvisitors.txt
```

Comment: Just moving `>reportvisitors.txt` to the `done` is sufficient to make the file be rewritten from the start for every run of the script. You don't need the `rm`, _or_ the switch to `>>`

Comment: Much better; the bugs that are still outstanding are ones that were still present in the OP's code. (I'd still suggest fixing them -- quoting `"$group1"`, `"$username`"` and `"$username"`).

Comment: You could replace the io redirection operator with a pipe to the tee utility; that way you can see the output as it runs rather than having to wait for the script to complete and then do a cat.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `>` instead of `>>` and it overwrites the data currently in that file during each iteration of your loop. To append text to a file you need to use `>>`  instead. Just modify your script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
username=username.txt

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
echo $username1 $group1
 if [[ $group1 == "visitor" ]]; then
   echo $username1 >> reportvisitors.txt
 fi
done < $username
```

If your only intention of this script is to just collect the vistors, you can achieve the same results in an `awk` one liner like this:

```sh
awk -F, '{if($2 == "visitor")print $1}' username.txt > reportvisitors.txt
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want multiple runs of the script to cause the file to have more than one set of output.

Answer (score 2):

First create a temporary file to print the results. You can do that with the `mktemp` utility. Then, if no errors occurred, move that file to `reportvisitors.txt`. Use `>>` instead of `>` to append to the temp file:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=username.txt
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
    if [ $group1 = "visitor" ]; then
        echo $username1 >> "$tmpfile"
    fi
done < $username

mv "$tmpfile" reportvisitors.txt
```

This avoids the issue where you lose the previous contents of `reportvisitors.txt` even if the script failed with an error.

Ideally, your script should have error handling and delete the temp file in case of errors.

Comment: Why re-open the `tmpfile` every time you want to `echo` a single line of output to it? If you open it just once, then you also don't need to switch from `>` to `>>`. (For example, put `exec >"$tmpfile"` right after `tmpfile=$(mktemp)`, and then every `echo` in the script will append to that already-open file handle by default).